# $\ f_{\theta}(y) = \frac{\theta}{2\sqrt{y}}\cdot e^{-\theta \sqrt{y}}$ with Gamma prior

Tags: statistics, bayesian

Let $\ Y_i \sim f_{\theta}(y) = \frac{\theta}{2\sqrt{y}}\cdot e^{-\theta \sqrt{y}},\ \ \ i = 1, \dots,n, \ \ y \ge 0,\ \ \theta \ge 0 $

I'm trying to find out if a gamma prior $\ (\alpha,\beta) $ will be a conjugate to the data

$$\ P(\theta |Y) = \frac{P(Y|\theta )\cdot P(\theta) }{P(Y)} \propto  P(Y|\theta)P(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y_i}} \cdot e^{-\theta \sqrt{y_i}} \cdot \frac{\theta^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta\theta} \beta^{\alpha}\\}{\Gamma(\alpha)}  
\\
\propto \frac{e^{-\theta\sum\sqrt{y_i}}}{2^n} \cdot \theta^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta\theta} \beta^{\alpha} \prod \sqrt{y_i}^{-1} $$

I can't really see how to proceed from here to something similar to the gamma density form (if possible) ?

Comment: The posterior pdf is exactly proportional to $\theta^{n+\alpha-1}\cdot e^{-(\sum \sqrt y_i+\beta)\theta}\,\mathbf1_{\theta>0}$ for $y_i\ge 0$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom can you show me the way ?

Comment: You have it already, except a missing $\theta^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your likelihood is

$$p(\mathbf{y}|\theta)\propto \theta^n e^{-\theta\sum\sqrt{ y}}$$

for the sake of simplicity I wasted  any quantity not depending on $\theta$

The prior is

$$\pi(\theta)\propto \theta^{a-1}e^{-b\theta}$$

thus to derive the posterior, simply multiply $\text{likelihood}\times\text{prior}$ obtaining

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{y})\propto \theta^{a+n-1}\cdot e^{-\theta(b+\sum\sqrt{ y})}$$

and we immediately recognize the kernel of a Gamma distribution

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{y})\sim\Gamma\left(a+n;b+\sum\sqrt{ y}\right)$$

If you want to get the exact posterior density simply normalize obtaining

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{y})=\frac{(b+\sum\sqrt{ y})^{a+n}}{\Gamma(a+n)}\theta^{a+n-1}\cdot e^{-\theta(b+\sum\sqrt{ y})}$$